# Cell by cell merge

Tags: r, merge

I have a table of counts in **R**:

```
Deg_Maj.tbl <- table(dat1$Maj,dat1$DegCat)
Deg_Maj.tbl

   B   D
A  66  5
C   2  9
```

and a table of percentages:

```
Deg_Maj.ptbl <- round(prop.table(Deg_Maj.tbl)*100,3)
Deg_Maj.ptbl

  B        D
A 80.48   6.10
C 2.44    10.98
```

I need to build a table that looks like this:

```
    B              D
A 66(80.48%)     5(6.1%)
C 2(2.44%)       9(10.98%)
```

I have several tables to do in this manner, so I am hoping to find a nice easy way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `paste`

```
Deg_Maj_out <- Deg_Maj.tbl
Deg_Maj_out[] <- paste0(Deg_Maj.tbl, "(", Deg_Maj.ptbl, "%)")
Deg_Maj_out
#   B          D        
#A 66(80.48%) 5(6.1%)  
#C 2(2.44%)   9(10.98%)
```